# How to highlight duplicate cells in excel?

Tags: excel, duplicates

For example:

Column A:

Bob <--Duplicate

Jane

Mary

Rick

Morty

Column B:

Larry

Eric

Dina

Bob <-- Duplicate

Fred

The duplicate cells should then highlight.

Comment: there is a conditional format rule to highlight duplicate values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select all cells with values, go to Conditional formatting ==> Highlight cells ==>Duplicate values.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1 -Select cells A1:A8.

2 -On Excel’s Home tab choose Conditional Formatting, Highlight Cells Rules, and then Duplicate Values.

3 - In this case, Excel displays the Duplicate Values dialog box and also provides a preview of the formatting to be applied to your worksheet, as shown in Figure 1. Notice that the Duplicate Values dialog box is dual-purpose, as you can choose Unique Values instead of Duplicates.

4 - If the default red/pink combination isn’t to your liking, click the drop-down list on the right and then choose Custom Format to display a Format Cells dialog box from which you can make a variety of choices. Click to confirm your choices.